# SSLError. Не удается отправить запрос

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, ssl

Я отправляю запрос:

```
response = requests.post(
    rkeeper_url, 
    auth = (login, password), 
    data = complete_request, 
    verify = False
)
```

но получаю ошибку, связанную с `SSL`. Знаю, что доступна версия `ssl 1.0`, пытаюсь вручную поменять версию в коде, но не работает, все равно получаю ошибку.

Ошибка:

`requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='host', port=port): Max retries exceeded with url: url (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:1123)')))`

Подскажите, как это исправить?

Comment: покажите код? что скрывается под rkeeper_url, complete_request etc?

Comment: rkeeper_url - это url, на который нужно послать запрос, к сожалению, полностью его показать не могу.  complete_request - это запрос в xml формате.
Как ни странно, на некоторых компьютерах запрос работает, но на одном (рабочем) нет, будто бы где-то блокируется

Comment: `def send_request(request):
    config = load_config()
    rkeeper_url = config["rkeeper_url"]
    login = config["login"]
    password = config["pswd"]

    complete_request = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><RK7Query>" + request + "</RK7Query>"
    response = requests.post(rkeeper_url, auth=(login, password), data=complete_request, verify=False)
    return _get_xml(response.text)
`

Comment: Получилось отправить запрос, если создаю специальный конфиг
`openssl_conf = openssl_init
[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect
[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect
[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1`
Но хотелось бы все таки, подправить код

Comment: @Anastasia Если только на рабочем компьютере не работает запрос, это точно блокировка протокола или порта, многие организации/компании это делают, т.е. блокируют на выходном в интернет шлюзе через файрволл. Да SSL как раз часто выдаёт подобную ошибку `Ошибка протокола`, когда заданный порт прерывается фарволлом. Один из вариантов это либо найти другой номер порта, который не блокирован. Если порт изменить нельзя, тогда второй вариант это прокси сервера использовать или VPN.Либо может есть HTTP (не HTTPS) порт, попробуйте `http://` префикс.Других простых решений больше нет для обхода блокировки